# Android Firebase notification have no sound

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting Firebase notification sound while app runs and not getting notification sound while app is in background. I don't know why it is happening.

This is what I tried

```
Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
            // To Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Sample Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gj512x512)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1, noBuilder.build());
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Do you mean when you are getting FCM notification right?

Comment: yes it is an fcm notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do one thing say your backend developer to just send **data** payload in the notification, ask him to restrict and remove **notification** payload,

Because when you are getting a notification at that time if your app in the background and you are getting notification payload at that time system handle notification from their side and that's why problem arise,

So simply just remove **notification** payload from the server-side and it will work fine.

Add your php code like bellow for data

```
$title = 'Whatever';
$message = 'Lorem ipsum';
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => ['deviceID'],
    'priority' => 'high',
    'data' => array(
        'body' => $message,
        'title' => $title,
        'sound' => 'default',
        'icon' => 'icon'
    )
);
```

Comment: what do you mean by notification payload?

Comment: First thing from where you are getting fcm notification?

Comment: Is from your server?

Comment: My concern is when you are preparing or sending fcm from PHP code at that time you need to change your payload or json data.

Comment: I am getting sound when app is running on foreground

Comment: I know, this is happing because when you are in foreground at that time your custom code executed from onReceive but when you are in the background at that time onReceive  will not be called that's why I am suggesting you change in fcm code,

Comment: Just put log inside your onReceive, log only will print if you are in the foreground if you are in the background then the log will not work.

Comment: If you want much detail then you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive

Answer (score 0):

```
 notificationChannel.setSound(null,null);  // remove this line 



.setSound(sound) //replace this line with this 

setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using FCM, you don't need to implement notification codes, **unless you need to customize it for your app** (for example special light, special sound, special vibration and...).
otherwise, you can just have a class like this and set manifest's things too

FCM Class:

```
public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    showNotification(Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getNotification()).getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "net.Test.id";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(body).setContentInfo("Info");
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.d("TOKEN", s);
}
}
```

manifest flie:

```
<service
        android:name="arbn.rahyab.rahpayadmin.data.network.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="001" />
```

if you want to customize it, write codes inside FCN class.

Comment: I'm sending notification from php code and I want to customize the notification sound

Comment: I edited my answer. there is a customized code too. I hope it helps you.